# Asset Library - videoplayerpage.aspx template currently in use edit and reload?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Template i.e `..\15\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\VideoAndRichMedia\videoplayerpage.aspx` can this be edited and reflect/force the changes in asset libraries that already exist?

Where are these template files stored once initally loaded into SharePoint Server?

Editing the template has no effect, I have to edit the `videoplayerpage.aspx` via the forms folder in each existing asset library.

Can I get access to the currently loaded source of the template or reload the template on the server?